# onCreateDialog is called after show?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement custom `DialogFragment`. But when I try to show it I am getting `NullPointerException`. Also as I have noticed `onCreateDialog` is never implictly called.
What is wrong with it. I have read official manual, and followed all steps in it [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
Here is my code for custom Dialog Fragment

```
 public class UserInputDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    InputDialogListener mListener;
    private EditText mTextEdit;

    public UserInputDialogFragment() {
        super();
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_input, null);
        builder.setView(mainView);
        mTextEdit = (EditText) mainView.findViewById(R.id.user_input);
        if (mTextEdit==null) {
            Log.e("ERROR","Text edit is null");
        }
        // Add action buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(UserInputDialogFragment.this,mTextEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_bnt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(UserInputDialogFragment.this,mTextEdit.getText().toString());
                UserInputDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    public interface InputDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String userInput);

        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog, String userInput);
    }


    public void showAndAddHint(FragmentManager manager,String tag,String hint) {
        this.onCreateDialog(null);
        mTextEdit.setHint(hint);
        this.show(manager,tag);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (InputDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InputDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to show dialog this way.

```
 UserInputDialogFragment userInputDialogFragment = new UserInputDialogFragment();
                    userInputDialogFragment.showAndAddHint(getFragmentManager(),"Please enter phone number",task.phoneNumber);
```

And here is `NullPointerException` `mTextEdit` is `null`.

```
public void showAndAddHint(FragmentManager manager,String tag,String hint) {
    this.onCreateDialog(null);
    mTextEdit.setHint(hint);
    this.show(manager,tag);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showAndAddHint` method won't work as written. What you should do instead is:

1 - Set a member variable `mHint = hint;`

2 - Call `show()` exactly the way you're doing it now.

3 - Read the member variable `mHint` in on create dialog and use it to set the edit text hint.

Don't call `onCreateDialog` explicitly because the show method does that for you when needed.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thx. Happy holidays and new year